# Como fazer importação de dados Mysql em aplicação Xamarin Forms?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, xamarin-forms

Bom dia! Estou com um dilema aqui. Preciso fazer uma importação de dados de um banco MySQL hospedado para minha aplicação em Xamarin.Forms e usar localmente, no SQLite. Sendo assim, o usuário importaria os dados do banco, usaria o app offline e localmente e depois, faria uma exportação dos dados de volta para o banco MySQL. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Fazer um dump da base da dados seria uma solução para o seu problema? É possível fazer o dump  do database inteiro, ou fazer granular por tabela. [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html)

Comment: opa, maravilha! como eu faria isso dentro da solucao xamarin.forms?

Comment: Uma vez eu fiz algo parecido no app, mas utilizando outra ótica... Quando o usuário do app solicitar os dados, na sua API, pegue os dados do mysql e converta-os em JSON, repassando para seu app. No App, deserialize os dados JSON e salve no SQLite... E depois para sincronizar os dados, faça vice-versa.